# Magento Error during unserialization

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a magneto based web shop with a custom template. The webshop works at first side fine except that during the loading of a page (every page) the following exception (see below) is thrown and Magento tries to load something that is not present: undefined?1479491943475 Anybody an idea how to fix this?  I use Magento 1.9.2.4

```
16-11-05T22:04:46+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Exception' with message 'Error during unserialization' in /home/fossilshop/public_html/lib/Unserialize/Parser.php:60
Stack trace:
#0 /home/fossilshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php(44): Unserialize_Parser->unserialize(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#1 /home/fossilshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Serialized.php(37): Mage_Core_Helper_UnserializeArray->unserialize(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#2 /home/fossilshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Data.php(78): Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Serialized->_afterLoad()
#3 /home/fossilshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(334): Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data->afterLoad()
#4 /home/fossilshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(229): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#5 /home/fossilshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(164): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->_initGroup(Object(Varien_Data_Form), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#6 /home/fossilshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Edit.php(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initForm()
#7 /home/fossilshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(107): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit->initForm()
#8 /home/fossilshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
#9 /home/fossilshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#10 /home/fossilshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /home/fossilshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /home/fossilshop/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /home/fossilshop/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
2016-11-05T22:04:46+00:00 ERR (3): 

> Blockquote
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently ran into this issue too and found this fix

> https://www.atwix.com/magento/supee-7405-cart-merge-error-fix/

After adding my own module with the above fix, the exception stopped logging.

Hope it helps